Lifting map from finite cyclic group to integers
Suppose $\phi:G \to \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is a group quotient with finite cyclic image. Under what conditions can $\phi$ be lifted to a homomorphism $\tilde \phi:G \to \mathbb Z$?
Specifically I'm interested in the case when $G$ is a nonabelian free group, but I'm curious if there's a general criterion. I think this might have something to do with group cohomology?

Since the arrival group is abelian you can suppose G is by quotienting by D(G)? Maybe it is a (too) bold statement. Then you need Ext(G,Z)=0 for this to work for any morphism otherwise it has to be in the kernel of the connexion morphism?

For a free group $G= \langle X \vert\,\, \rangle$, any map (of sets) $X\to \mathbb{Z}$ determines a homomorphism $G\to \mathbb{Z}$.  Thus for each $x\in X$ we just need to map $x$ to any integer $n_x$ such that $n_x \mod n$ is $\phi(x)$.  Thus the map always lifts in this case.
In general $G= \langle X \vert R \rangle$.  If we map $x\mapsto n_x$ as before, then we get induced a map (of sets) $R\mapsto n\mathbb{Z}$, which we can think of as a cocycle in $\alpha\in H^2(G;\mathbb{Z}$).
A different choice of integers $n_x$ would give a different cocycle $\alpha'\in H^2(G;\mathbb{Z})$, which differs from $\alpha$ by a coboundary.  Conversely, if $\alpha'$ differs from $\alpha$ by a coboundary, then some choice of integers $n_x$ will result in the cocycle $\alpha'$.  Thus as an element of $H^2(G;\mathbb{Z})$, $\alpha$ is well defined independently of choices of $n_x$.
Clearly $\phi$ lifts if and only if some choice of the $n_x$ will result in the $0$ cocycle, which happens if and only if $\alpha=0$ as an element of $H^2(G;\mathbb{Z})$.
This all follows more or less immediately from the definition of group cohomology, taking $$\cdots\to\mathbb{Z}G^R\to \mathbb{Z}G^X\to \mathbb{Z}G\dashrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$$ as your projective resolution.

As I was saying in my comment, the functor $P:G \mapsto G/D(G)$ from groups to abelian groups where $D(G)$ is the subgroup generated by commutators is the left adjoint of the "inclusion functor" $F:A \mapsto A$ from the category of abelian group to the category of groups. So you have binatural isomorphisms
$$\hom_{\mathbf{Grp}} (G,F(A)) \simeq \hom_\mathbf{Ab} (P(G),F(A))$$
What you desire to know is if $\psi$ is in the image of the morphism
$$\pi_* : \hom_\mathbf{Grp} (G,\mathbb{Z}) \to \hom_\mathbf{Grp} (G,\mathbb{Z}/ n \mathbb{Z})$$
where $\pi: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. The previous observation tells you that you might as well study if $\bar\psi$ (the image of $\psi$ by the previous iso) is in the image of
$$\pi_* : \hom_\mathbf{Ab} (P(G),\mathbb{Z}) \to \hom_\mathbf{Ab} (P(G),\mathbb{Z}/ n \mathbb{Z})$$.
Notice that since the functor $\hom (P(G),\_ )$ is cohomological, you have an exact sequence:
$$\hom (P(G),\mathbb{Z}) \to \hom (P(G),\mathbb{Z}/ n \mathbb{Z}) \to \operatorname{Ext} (P(G),\mathbb{Z})$$
Where the fist morphism is $\pi_*$ and the second $\delta_\sharp$ the connexion morphism. So in general if you want to always have a lift, you need to ensure $\delta_\sharp = 0$ (or better $\operatorname{Ext}(P(G),\mathbb{Z}) = 0)$, otherwise you need $\delta_\sharp (\bar{\psi}) = 0$.
Notice that $\operatorname{Ext}(P(G),\mathbb{Z}) \simeq \hom(P(G) , \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) \simeq \hom(G,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$

In English, they are called "commutators", not "derivators". And what you call the "free functor" is called the inclusion functor.

Ok thanks! I'll edit it

And it should be the subgroup generated by commutators, as the set of commutators is not always a subgroup.
